# Rotate mp4 using jcodec

Tags: android, rotation, mp4, jcodec

Is there a way to rotate mp4 files using Jcodec? I am able to add/edit meta data using Jcodec but could not find a way to change the rotation of the video. For example if the mp4 file is in portrait, I want to change the orientation to landscape.

Below is the code to add the album art to MP4 file using Jcodec.

```
MetadataEditor mediaMeta = MetadataEditor.createFrom(new
    File("file.mp4"));
Map<Integer, MetaValue> meta = mediaMeta.getItunesMeta();
meta.put(0xa9415254, MetaValue.createString("New value")); // fourcc for '©ART'
mediaMeta.save(false); // fast mode is off
```

Similarly, I am looking to change the rotation of MP4 file.

I tried to change the rotation using the tagid from this [link](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html#TrackHeader) but could not do it.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Have you tried using the `rotation-degrees` key?

Comment: Thank you @MikhailOlshanski for your response. rotation-degrees key isn't working.